# How to inherit Require directives from a parent directory?

Tags: apache-2.4

I'm trying to have a directory structure where each user has a directory under `/restricted` that only they can access, but the "admin" user has access to all and `OPTIONS` requests aren't restricted.

Here's my config right now:

```
<Directory "/restricted">
  <LimitExcept OPTIONS>
    Require user admin
  </LimitExcept>
</Directory>

<Directory "/restricted/foo">
  <LimitExcept OPTIONS>
    Require user foo
  </LimitExcept>
</Directory>

<Directory "/restricted/bar">
  <LimitExcept OPTIONS>
    Require user bar
  </LimitExcept>
</Directory>
```

This doesn't work since (to the best of my understanding) `Require` directives from subfolders override the `Require` from the parent. This sounds like a good default, but I was wondering if I can override that behavior somehow?

I'm aware I can also just include "admin" in every `Require`, e.g. `Require user bar admin`, but this seems a bit error-prone, so I'd avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Authmerging Or" in every sub-directory, would that be less error prone?

```
<Directory "/restricted">
  <LimitExcept OPTIONS>
    Require user admin
  </LimitExcept>
</Directory>

<Directory "/restricted/foo">
  AuthMerging Or
  <LimitExcept OPTIONS>
    Require user foo
  </LimitExcept>
</Directory>

<Directory "/restricted/bar">
  AuthMerging Or
  <LimitExcept OPTIONS>
    Require user bar
  </LimitExcept>
</Directory>
```